# GitHub CodeSpaces with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, vscode-devcontainer, github-codespaces, devcontainer

### Introduction

Currently, I'm promgramming a project that use JavaFX, and I wanted to uses GitHub CodeSpaces with JavaFX, but I didn't found any documentation to do it.

### Question

Somemone know if is possible to use GitHub CodeSpaces with JavaFX, if yes how we do it ?

---

#### Update

I have used GitHub Devcontainer with java 17 and followed this instructions:[openjfx getting started hello world instructions for Maven (or Gradle)](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven)

The configuration of the dev container:

```json
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/java
{
    "name": "Java",
    // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/java:0-17",

    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/java:1": {
            "version": "none",
            "installMaven": "true",
            "installGradle": "false"
        }
    },
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "shrey150.javafx-support"
            ]
        }
    },

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    "postCreateCommand": "sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxxf86vm1 libgl1-mesa-glx"

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    // "customizations": {},

    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "root"
}
```

The current error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$6(GtkApplication.java:202)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:200)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:40)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:290)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:292)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        ... 5 more
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:491)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:453)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:491)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:453)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:342)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:330)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:160)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:827)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:272)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:195)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.267 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-02T07:00:03Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run (default-cli) on project sample: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Looking at the codespaces doc, you can configure a JDK 17+ environment with Maven or Gradle.  Once that is done, you can follow the [openjfx getting started hello world instructions for Maven (or Gradle)](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven).  That is in theory (I did not try it).  If you haven't used either Maven or Gradle, I advise starting with Maven.

Comment: IMO, there will be no beginner-style instructions for what you are trying to do.  My advice is that, if you have to ask, don't do it.  Instead, use a standard IDE locally.  I recommend the IntelliJ community edition with the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) with Maven.  Or follow the instructions at openjfx.io for other IDEs, if you much prefer them.

Comment: @jewelsea Thank you for your comment, I have updated the post with your suggestions

Comment: Have you [installed](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) "an  appropriate JavaFX runtime for your operating system?"

Comment: @trashgod I used Maven installation: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Comment: I'm curious about the "the Extension Pack for Java" required for [tag:maven].

Comment: looks like https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6184 / https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/550 .."please try" (tldr;) `"runArgs":["-e", "DISPLAY=${env:DISPLAY}"]` ("in linux" ..."in windows": "vcvars"+read deeper)